# How to send 2 array in servlet

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I sending a 2 array in my servlet but i don't know how to send my second array in javascript to my servlet I hope someone help me with this thank you.

```
<label for="pets">Choose your Vegetables:</label>
        <select class="selectpicker" name="vegetables-selected"  id="vege" multiple aria-label="size 3 select example">
        <option value="Carrot">Carrot</option>
         <option value="Broccoli">Broccoli</option>
         <option value="Cabbage">Cabbage</option>
         <option value="Cucumber">Cucumber</option>
         <option value="Mushroom">Mushroom</option>
</select>

<label for="pets">Choose your pets:</label>
        <select class="selectpicker" name="vegetables-selected"  id="pets" multiple aria-label="size 3 select example">
        <option value="dog">dog</option>
         <option value="car">car</option>
         <option value="snake">snake</option>
</select>

<Script>

document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function() {
    var selected = [];
    var selected2 = [];
    
    for (var option of document.getElementById('vege').options
            var option of document.getElementById('pets').options)
    {
        if (option.selected) {
            selected.push(option.value);
        }
    }
    document.location.href = 'output?selected='+ selected  ;
}
</Script>
```

**OUTPUT**
Broccoli,Cucumber,Potato      null

Comment: Also, I can't help but notice other mistakes: 

- your `<label>`s are `for` the same `<select>`
- your `<select>`s both have the same `name`

Comment: You do not need this JavaScript at all. Your root mistake is just that you confused `name` with `id`. See abovelinked duplicate for the proper approach.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (var option of document.getElementById('vege').options
>            var option of document.getElementById('pets').options)
> ```

1. I'm sorry, but what is this? For-loops do NOT work like that.
2. Why not just create a model class, on the front end, that represent the data on the page (look into MV* design patterns), and use the **model** to represent/send your data. Think something like:

`src/models/YourPreferencesModel.js` (or something similar)

```
class YourPreferencesModel extends BaseModel { 
   constructor(vegetables = [], pets = []) { 
        super();
        this.vegetables = vegetables;
        this.pets = pets;
    }
}
```

and then have your `BaseModel` be like:

`src/models/BaseModel.js` (or something similar)

```
class BaseModel { 
    /**
     * @param { (success : boolean) => {} } onDone
     **/
    save(onDone) { 
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", '[your_endpoint_here]');
        
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
        xhr.onload = () => {
            onDone((xhr.status >= 200) && (xhr.status < 400));
        }
        
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(this));
    }
    
    // something similar for get() method
}
```

and at the `<head>` of your HTML file,

```
<script src="src/models/BaseModel.js" />
<script src="src/models/YourPreferencesModel.js" />
```

create the model in a view-model (or controller) class, instantiated on start, have the view components update that model through the view-model/controller, and move the submit handling to the view-model/controller. Your `onclick` in the view would then call the `save()` of the view-model/controller, which would then call the `save()` of the model.

**DISCLAIMER**: I have not run this code, so, as always, anyone viewing code on questions on code forums should check it.

Also this code is using the old-school [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readystatechange_event). You could modernize it with [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), jQuery's `post()`, ..., *anything* you have on your end. That would greatly simplify the model methods.

> ```
> document.location.href = 'output?selected='+ selected  ;
> ```

Also, you're simply changing the page URL, hence making a GET request to your server with the data. No. This needs to be a POST request.